# List Comprehension returns empty list

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, list-comprehension

I'm trying to query a MongoDB database and throw the two sets of results ('_id' and 'Team') into two separate lists.

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost:27017')
db = client['db_name']

query = {'Team': {'$exists': 1}}
projection = {'_id': 1, 'Team': 1}

data = db['collection_name'].find(query, projection)  # line 9

id_list = [value for dict in data for key, value in dict.iteritems() if key == '_id']
teams_list = [value for dict in data for key, value in dict.iteritems() if key == 'Team']

print id_list
print teams_list

client.close()
```

For the code above, the 'id_list' is as expected but 'teams_list' is empty. When I put 'teams_list' before 'id_list' I get the expected 'teams_list' output and 'id_list' is empty. And when I repeat the data call (line 9) in between the two list comprehensions I get the expected output for both lists.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Presumably, `find()` returns a generator, which is consumed when you iterate it.

Comment: You need to define `data` as: `data = list(db['collection_name'].find(query, projection))`. Note: `list(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your `data` as:

```
data = list(db['collection_name'].find(query, projection))
```

As `find()` returns the generator. Once you iterate the values, those are lost. You need to store them as `list`. Here `list()` does that i.e. stores the items returns by generator as list.

Instead of iterating the list twice, better way will be two do it single loop as:

```
id_list, teams_list = [], []

#   v  `dict` is in-built data type, you should not be using it as variable
for d in data:
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        if key == '_id':
            id_list.append(value)
        elif key == 'Team':
            teams_list.append(value)
```

Refer [Generator wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for more information related to generators

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. How do I know find() returns a generator - in MongoDB I believe they call it a cursor...is that the same thing?

Comment: Check this document related to Generators: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned the culprit here is the [`find()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) method which returns a `Cursor` object which is consumed when you iterate it the first time.

But you are using the wrong method for the job. You need to use the [`.aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method.

```
query = {'Team': {'$exists': 1}}

cursor = db['collection_name'].aggregate([ 
    {'$match': query }
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': None,
        'id_list': {'$push': '$_id'},
        'teams_list': {'$push': '$Team'}
    }}
])
```

The `.aggregate()` method like his partner in crime `.find()` returns a [`CommandCursor`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor) over the result set which is a *generator* like object.

Because we are grouping by `None`, iterating the cursor will yield a single document which means that you can safely do:

```
print list(cursor)[0] # return a dictionary
```

or

```
result = list(cursor)[0]
print result['id_list']
print result['teams_list']
```